# Property not calling change listener unless there's an invalidation listener as well, what's wrong?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm setting up a listener for the `isShown` property of a `Stage` in JavaFX:

```
stage.showingProperty().addListener((observable, old, showing) -> {
    if (showing) {
        System.out.println("Now it's shown");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Now it's hidden");
    }
});
```

I have a complex logic that may cause the stage to not be shown when the app starts (it just shows a tray bar icon). When it starts hidden, the first time I show it, the listener doesn't get any notification. Afterwards it starts working normally. I tried to reproduce it in a minimum example but I haven't been able yet.

What's weird is that if I add an invalidation listener:

```
stage.showingProperty().addListener(observable -> { });
```

It works as expected. The change listener starts to get called even from the first change.

What could possible cause this behavior?

Comment: Are you showing the Stage from the JavaFX application thread?

Comment: @VGR: yes, I am, by using `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? - I'm experiencing very similar behaviour